# Why appendChild is not working with node type?

Tags: javascript, nodes, appendchild

This might be a little too simple for me to diagnose, but I'm wondering why am I not able to add 'img' to the 'div'.

console does pass the images but it's not appending. I want to remove the elements after.

Thanks in advance

```
var theLeft = document.createElement('div');
var theLeftElements = theLeftSide.getElementsByTagName('img');
theLeftSide.appendChild(theLeft);
theLeft.appendChild(theLeftElements);
```

Comment: What programming language and/or framework is this?  Please tag appropriately.

Comment: @BJMyers Sure, thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList` (Similar to an array), whereas `appendChild` expects its argument to be a `Node`.

You will need to iterate over the list yourself:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for( var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++ ) {
    parent.appendChild( imgs[i] );
}
```